# Why can't tinyint store more than the number 255 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, tinyint

If TINYINT can store three characters, for example, why can't it store up to the number 999?

Comment: Actually, it can store up to 255, not 256, because 0 is also a value. Furthermore, if its signed, your range is cut up by half, meaning you can store from -128 up to 127.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it takes only `8` bit and hence can encode no more than `2^8 = 256` values.

The three characters you see in something like `'123'` are the result of the binary to decimal conversion. You cannot store arbitrary `3` characters there.

Answer (score 4):

It is 8 bits and can actually store a maximum value of 255. 8 bits have 256 possible states including zero.